# Recover session in sublime

Tags: windows, sublimetext3

I just updated Sublime from Build 3103 to Build 3114 and lost my session: After the update I started Sublime and got a blank session instead of my old one. I'm using Windows 10. Is there a way to get my old session back? I've got a lot of unsaved tabs there which normally are saved automatically in sublime. So I'm worried about tabs which never were saved to a file. I'm not worried about the files which were opened and have to be opened again now.

Comment: This is a serious problem, I have no solution for it. I have also updated to new version 3114 on windows 10 but my session was maintained. Session is usually saved in `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session` including the non saved contents, but in your case this file should have been already overwrited by the new blank session.

Comment: @sergioFC Yeah, it's already overwritten. I searched my whole drive, there is no further `Session.sublime_session` file. So sublime did no backup before updating (with the same file name). Is it possible that it can still be recovered from my drive (ssd) because the old version is not overwritten yet there?

Comment: Perhaps, usually when a file is deleted, the OS doesn't overwritte its content on disc because it is a time-expensive operation, instead it simply removes the file name from the file list and marks the disc space as empty space, so that other files can use that space. The more a filesystem is used, the most likely some empty space is used by other file. There are free tools that allows you to find files in the "unused" space. In this case, the file might have not been deleted but simply modified, so maybe the old content (or part of it) is already overwritted.

Comment: Please file a bug report at the [Sublime Text Issues (Core)](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core) repo, but first please take a look at [this template](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/blob/master/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md) for reporting. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a workaround which helped me to recover the contents of the emptied file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2680/138115 ~ read the comments too